# Python f-string name "blabla is not defined" error when trying to insert a string into string

Tags: python, string, f-string

Okay, so to start off I am trying to insert a string into code that I made into string.

Here's what I mean:

```
x="achievement"

data= f"{x}_scores:[{ score: { type: number}},"
```

Trying to insert `x` into the the string using f-string.

But it keeps saying

```
NameError: name 'score' is not defined
```

This is a test I'm doing for a bigger project.

Note that the string I'm inserting into is code I turned into string because I need to insert 100+ words into similar strings, and I can't do it by hand. I'm just trying to generate a list and copy and paste the output elsewhere.

I absolutely need to insert it into that format. Can I get some help?

Comment: Are you sure it's complaining about `{x}` and not `{ score: { type: number}}` did you try escaping the latter?

Comment: use doubled `{` and `}`: `f"{x}_scores:[{{score: {{type: number}}}},"`

Comment: @Skam That's what I'm saying. It says "score is not defined". I assume it's the "[{" characters because I tried it in a normal string statement and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
x = "achievement"

data = f"{x}_scores:""[{score: { type: number}},"

print(data)
```

Output:

```
achievement_scores:[{score: { type: number}},
```

---

The `""` I inserted in between `{x}_scores:` and `[{score: { type: number}},` tells python to only perform the `f` on the first half of the string, and then append the second half after the evaluation.

Comment: That is not how you escape curly braces in f-string.

Comment: @Asocia It's a simple fix to the problem.